# Is better to use a multiclass classifier or a set of binary classifiers?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, binary-data, unbalanced-classes, multi-class

I have to build a general method to perform multiclass classification. The number of class in the target variable is not fixed (it is probably in a range between 3 and 10).

I would like to know if **it better to train a multiclass classifier or many binary classifier**.
I am looking for a general method able to well performing even with 3 and 10 classes.

For what I know, the multiclass classifier is better since it allows to train the algorithm only once and also to keep into consideration the relationship between the target classes. On the other hand the binary classifiers are good since it is possible to exploit the potential of more algorithms that could be trained only in the binary cases. The cons of the multiple binary classifiers are mainly about the runtime (it is necessary to perform several training procedures) and the class imbalances.

Right now, I prefer a single multiclass classifier. Are there other pros/cons or some general rule about this choice?